# Symfony and Doctrine - Getting all entities including their translations using Translatable

Tags: symfony, doctrine, translation

I'm trying to get all the records from one of my Doctrine tables including its translations (I'm using Doctrine Translatable). The reason for this is that I want to allow the user to edit all the data before submitting. I'm having some Google Maps markers which have translated descriptions. I want to allow the administrator to edit them on the client-side UI built with javascript / jQuery. I don't want to download and update the data for each marker move, that's why I decided to take this approach.

Right now I'm successfully sending all the data (even the translated parts) to the UI, but it requires quite a lot of queries to be made. First I pull all the default data from the database and then translate each record. Dreadful solution, I know. I want to refactor this piece of code to require one to two queries per request. My first idea was to create a query which would have inner queries for the translations. I abandoned this idea because of the complexity and I didn't want to load the translations table directly.

The next idea was about using two same queries but with the different translation hints. After executing the two queries, I would create model objects which would hold all the needed data and go on from there. This brought me very close to solution but I'm still having a problem. Once I set a hint to retrieve a translation, both queries (translated and original) return translated results. Here's my code so far:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$qb = $em->getRepository('SomeSite\SiteBundle\Entity\News')
    ->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->select();

$q1 = $qb->getQuery();
$q2 = $qb->getQuery();

$q2->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker');
$q2->setHint(\Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, 'en');

$en = $q2->getResult();

$q1->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker');
$q1->setHint(\Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, 'hr');

$hr = $q1->getResult();
var_dump($hr);
var_dump($en);
```

This is just a piece of code for testing (done on the News entity). Both of these dumps produce the same translated results. Here is one of the many links I read which lead me to this point:

https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/issues/771

So I suppose my questions are as follows. Can anyone tell me if this is would be considered the correct approach? Does anyone have a better idea to solve this quickly? And finally and most importantly, does anyone know how to make this work?

Thank you for your insights and time.

**EDIT:**
I managed to take a look at the bundle pointed to by nifr, but I'm having some issues. I followed the example from [this](http://knpbundles.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle) page.

First things first, when I try to update the schema, it throws me an error saying "Class 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException' not found in GalleryTranslation.php on line 146".

If I refresh my page, it says "Runtime Notice: Declaration of GalleryTranslation::setObject() should be compatible with Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonalTranslation::setObject($object)" although I used the Symfony code generation to generate it (generate entities).

Lastly, the code generation did not set the id object as id, so sometimes I get an error saying that translation entity does not have an id set.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to the multiple queries problem? I am having this problem as well, translation works but in some pages I have up to 100 doctrine queries generated!

Comment: In the end I went with a custom solution. For each table that I need translated values for I have another table whose name ends with "Localized" (e.g. "Country" and "CountryLocalized"). The first table has the main id and the values that don't need translation (stuff like integers, foreign keys...). It has one-to-many connection with the second one. The second one has a unique locale column, and contains one row per locale with the translated values for the single row in the first table. When I'm pulling the record, I do a join between the two columns using the primary key and the locale.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [a2lix/TranslationFormBundle](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle) which solves exactly this situation.

It's quite easy to setup and supports DoctrineExtensions **AND** KnpDoctrineBehaviors.

I've been using it in production several times now.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I finally got the time to take a look at the bundle you mentioned. I'm having some trouble using it. I would really appreciate you taking a look at my edited post and see if you can help me once again. Thank you very much!